# Trouble shoot goals in google analytics, not working

Tags: google-analytics

Adwords conversions are working but analytics goals are not working. it happens in a couple of sites the same issue. Could it be that I have third party tools? Like Hotjar and SurveyMonkey. I enable the preview mode of tag manager and some pages aren't tracked, but the thank you page it is and its show. In real-time appears the events but in the behavior report, no events registered.

Any idea of what could be?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal configuration is correct, just wait few hours and goals will appear.

Comment: the goals are created a long time ago and nothing happens

Comment: Show me the configuration, pls